# Upgraded to PHP 5.4 and now facebook link stats I was pulling no longer show on site

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, file-get-contents, json

I've been running a photography site for just over two years and displayed stats about how many facebook likes and shares each image page has accumulated underneath each image.

The code I have used to get this info and put it into the variables is this:

```
<?php   // Get Facebook Stats for Shares Likes Comments etc...
    $url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=".urlencode($this->canonicalurl);
    $xml = file_get_contents($url);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $shares = number_format($xml->link_stat->share_count);
    $likes = number_format($xml->link_stat->like_count);
    $comments = number_format($xml->link_stat->comment_count);
    $total = number_format($xml->link_stat->total_count);
?>
```

All was fine until today I switched from PHP5.2 to 5.4 and suddenly all the stats no longer appear. I've read around a little bit and some people were saying that I need to set allow_url_fopen = 1 but that was already set.

Someone else was saying that it may have something to do with using file_get_contents, but I got no concrete result.

Can anyone please shed some light on what might be wrong? Is there another way to write the above without using file_get_contents that would get around this issue if that is to blame?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is that the number_format needs to be a double, but $xml is an object. You can just remove number_format, but I recommend intval for it.

```
<?php   // Get Facebook Stats for Shares Likes Comments etc...
    $url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=".urlencode($this->canonicalurl);
    $xml = file_get_contents($url);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $shares = intval($xml->link_stat->share_count);
    $likes = intval($xml->link_stat->like_count);
    $comments = intval($xml->link_stat->comment_count);
    $total = intval($xml->link_stat->total_count);
?>
```